# How to refresh many capacitors quickly

Tags: capacitor, embedded, dac, charge, board

I'm working in an embedded space, where I need to keep voltages on a bunch of capacitors (RC circuits). Currently, I have an EEPROM with some data value for each capacitor. There is 1 DAC that feeds a bunch of multiplexers. The multiplexers are selected and enabled such that only 1 capacitor is connected to the DAC output at a time, which charges that capacitor up to its desired value. The MCU loops through the EEPROM data and selects each capacitor to be charged in turn, thereby maintaining charge on all the caps.

My issue is that I want to scale this system up. The charge on the capacitors cannot droop below a certain threshold, so I need to run this loop fast enough to prevent that from happening. With on the order of 50 capacitors, I'm fine. But with on the order of 1,500 capacitors, I will not be able to maintain all the charge.

So how can I maintain the charge on all these caps? My first thought is I need to parallelize. Adding another DAC (or DACs) would allow me to charge up 2 (or more) capacitors at once, which would effectively double (or more) my refresh speed.

Can this be done in some other way? Maybe other different hardware? I'm looking for advice on how to solve this issue. Use an FPGA possibly?

The problem would be solved with one DAC for every output, but I don't want 1500 DACs on my board.

EDIT:

**Goal**: I need to maintain charge on 1,500 capacitors.

**Problem**: The existing board (a 50-capacitor system) works, but will not scale up. Using the same methods, I will not be able to recharge 1,500 capacitors quickly enough.

**Potential Solution**: Add more DACs to the system to charge capacitors in parallel.

**Desired Assistance**: A solution that will maintain the charge on all the capacitors without letting them droop too low **OR** a suggestion of another variable that I can tweak to make the system work **OR** some reassurance that this is actually a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: software uses hardware accelerators, logic can write that fast no problem.  the codecs are done in part in dedicated logic so that the software doesnt have to do all the processing.  if you back this up to what width and speed your pcie link is say 5GT/s x8, its not that hard to move that much data across the bus into the card and the card has logic and likely many gpus to feed that data toward the memory.

Comment: when you use an ADC you dont sample the comparitors manually, there is logic in there that does it you use a slow bus to talk to something that is much faster that is doing the work for you.  no different here.

Comment: Displaying an image is not a software problem, it is hardware with wide high bandwidth busses and memories. There is no "processor" writing pixels. (well execept in some special cases, or a long time ago some computers used CPUs or automatons to reprogram on the fly video registers (ex. Amiga))

Comment: Brute force. If it's not working, you're not using enough of it.

Comment: You are asking two rather different questions. What do you want to know: how it is done or how you can do it?

Comment: _" I'm working in an embedded space (but not a display screen) where I need to repeatedly write to many registers and/or DACs over and over."_ - then ask questions about that, not about something unrelated. _"For the most part, the data itself does not change. However, it still **needs to be written over and over again**."_ - why?

Comment: @Oldfart I'm seeking some implementation advice for my application and I was also curious about monitors in particular.

Comment: @BruceAbbott You're right, it's a badly framed question. I will post a new one instead.

Comment: @jsotola Okay, I will edit it. These responses have made me reconsider the problem statement and I will post an edit once I gather my thoughts properly.

Comment: Get yourself a HD-SDI serialiser chip and clock it with 148.5MHz using DDR and you have a 1.485Gbs data stream.

Comment: It can go very simple or somewhat complex. The simplest is still SPI: most of the screen is static so you can use SPI to update a subset of pixels and leave the rest unchanged in the screen's internal memory. Or you can use a parallel bus to DMA data into the display. Modern displays uses more efficient buses but the principal is the same.

Comment: Not really sure what your task is, but could you just not double buffer? Have a main buffer constantly feeding  your DACs at the proper rate to maintain the picture, and a shadow buffer that you manipulate on your own time. Then when you are done, switch out the buffer en masse. That's how I would go about making a NTSC HUD display: the FPGA maintains the screen picture while the microcontroller slowly constructs the next screen to be displayed.

Comment: The question is now much more clear and specific.

Comment: It's now a completely different question! The original question seemed to be about digital graphic displays. This one is all about maintaining charge on 1500 capacitors! The overall effect of the edit is to give a very strong impression that you have a problem and think you have a solution but you're not going to explain what the real problem is.

Comment: @Transistor yes, sorry the original question was so far off that I wanted to post a new one. However, I was told to edit this one instead. I have described what I think might be a solution, but it feels like a bad way to solve the problem, so I was hoping some more experienced people could weigh in and suggest some alternate solutions. I am relatively new to the field, and as such, I might not be aware of traditional or alternative solutions to problems like this.

Comment: That's fine, but your question doesn't explain (or I can't see it) what you are trying to build. *I have described what I think might be a solution, but it feels like a bad way to solve the problem ...* Exactly! You are asking for help with your solution to a problem that we know nothing about. Hit the edit link again and explain what the overall problem is and why you have selected your "solution".

Comment: @Transistor thank you for your advice. I have edited the question.

Comment: No, explain the **overall** problem. If you have the data stored in EEPROM why do you need to maintain voltages on capacitors? Specify **exactly** what you mean, with actual voltage values, by "droop too low". We also need to know the value of the capacitors, their ESR, and what kind of dielectric they have.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the data values are received digitally and modified with some digital calculations. The reason I need the voltage on the capacitors is to drive analog devices. These devices accept voltages in the range of approx. 0-48V, and the capacitors are 10nF rated at 100V with a 20K resistor for the RC. The voltages should not droop below about 95-98% of their set value. I don't know the exact number on this, but it's very close.

Comment: I agree with Elliot that you haven't explained the overall problem You think that whatever it is can be solved by storing voltages on capacitors. Since we don't know what the overall problem is we suspect that you have gone down a rabbit hole of your own making.

Comment: I could rephrase the entire situation like this: I have 1500 devices that each have 1 analog voltage input. Each device needs to be held constant at a target voltage. I have access to the target voltages in the form of 14-bit digital numbers. How can I hold all the devices at their target voltage? Is that a better description of the overall problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109061/discussion-on-question-by-nullromo-how-to-refresh-many-capacitors-quickly).